# Embarrassing error when reading string literal into a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, hexdump

I feel semi-retarded posting this, but I have no idea why my program is blowing up when it reads a string literal from the keyboard (i.e. then assigning it to a pointer).

Been debugging for over an hour and the program keeps blowing up when it reads from the keyboard.

I have tried everything to fix this.  Initializing the string to a string literal (i.e. the compiler said it had a problem with nullptr).  It is almost like I have an invisible character somewhere.  If anyone can tell me what I'm doing wrong, I would greatly appreciate it.

**main.cpp**

```
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <crtdbg.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "protocol.h"

int main()
{
_CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);

int menuChoice = 0;

char * fileName = nullptr;
char * byteArray = nullptr;
char * hexArray = nullptr;
int numberOfBytes = 0;

PrintMenu();
GetMenuChoice(menuChoice);
ExecuteMenuChoice(menuChoice, fileName, byteArray, hexArray, numberOfBytes);

return 0;
}
```

**protocol.cpp**

```
void GetFile(char * fileName)
{

//Prompt user for binary file
std::cout << "\nEnter filename: " << std::endl;

//Read in location of binary file
std::cin.ignore(std::cin.rdbuf()->in_avail());
std::cin.getline(fileName, 256);
std::cin.clear();
std::cin.ignore(std::cin.rdbuf()->in_avail());
}
```

**protocol.h**

```
#ifndef PROTOCOL_H
#define PROTOCOL_H

//Function declarations
void PrintMenu();
void GetMenuChoice(int &menuChoice);
void ExecuteMenuChoice(int menuChoice, char *& fileName, char *& byteArray,
                   char *& hexArray, int numberOfBytes);
void NewLine();
void ThankUser();
void ErrorMessage();

#endif
```

Comment: Its not a string literal unless it is a string present in source code.

Comment: You need to do `char fileName[255];` so it has a place to put the string.

Comment: I suspect `std::cin.getline(fileName, 256);` right away. But you don't even show how it is being used. Where is the minimal example reproducing the problem?

Comment: Retarded? I believe what you meant to say is you might have an [intellectual disability](http://blogs.suntimes.com/sweet/2010/10/obama_signs_rosas_law_mental_r.html)!!

Comment: What does "the program keeps blowing up" mean?

Comment: Lose the `char *fileName` (for that matter *all* the `char *`s in this code) and use `std::string` instead.

Comment: I agree, this question would be rather embarrassing...

Comment: @Patashu: Why `255`? Isn't that a little prone to buffer overruns?

Comment: @jJohnsyweb Not if you don't try to fill it with more than 255 characters :0

Answer (score 2):

The code you have posted is incomplete but I don't see you allocating fileName before calling `std::cin.getline(fileName, 256)`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anywhere you *call* `GetFile` but it looks like it expects either an allocated buffer or an array of char.  In `main()` you declare a `char *fileName` but don't allocate any memory for it.  If you called (from `main()`) `GetFile(fileName)` then I would expect it to crash.  You either need to allocate space in `main()` or in `GetFile()` for reading the data.

Answer (score 0):

Passing a string literal to be populated does not make any sense. You need to pass a buffer:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h> // for _MAX_PATH

int main()
{
    char filename[_MAX_PATH];

    GetFile(filename);

    std::cout << filename << std::endl;
}
```

[**`_MAX_PATH`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/930f87yf.aspx) makes a little more sense than hard-coding an arbitrary value like `256`.

Better still would be use a [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and remove those buffer sizes entirely!

```
#include <iostream>

void GetFile(std::string& fileName)
{
    std::cout << "\nEnter filename: " << std::endl;

    std::getline(std::cin, fileName);
}

int main()
{
    std::string filename;

    GetFile(filename);

    std::cout << filename << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thank you guys and sorry for the stupid question.  Got it working. :)

Comment: @MrPickle5: Happy to help. [When you have decided which answer is the most helpful to you, mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq/#howtoask)

Answer (score 0):

cin::getline() does not allocate memory for you to store the string literals into `fileName`. You must provide memory space for it, by allocating memory to `fileName`, just like

```
fileName = new char[_MAX_PATH];
```

at last, don't forget to release the memory by

```
delete[] fileName;
```

Comment: `malloc()` and `free()`? Isn't this question tagged [tag:c++]?

Comment: c++ does not reject `malloc` & `free`, it is multi-paradigm. However, `new` & `free` should be a better choice :-)

Comment: Not rejecting these functions does not mean that they are idiomatic C++. Using `new` as you have edited is closer to C++ style, but this needs to be coupled with `delete []`. Since you know the size at compile time, it would make more sense to allocate the memory on the stack as in my answer.

Comment: thanks :-) I'd prefer to use `std::string` in practice, rather than allocate memory on stack, though the size is known at compile time. I like to keep stack small, to avoid potential stack overflow as possible.